# Understanding System.Uri

Tags: c#

```
StreamResourceInfo sri;
sri = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("WebBrowserIsoStorage;component/Images/textmate.jpg", UriKind.Relative)); 
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(sri.Stream)) 
{ 
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(imageStream)) 
    { 
        while (sri.Stream.Position < sri.Stream.Length) 
        { 
            writer.Write(reader.ReadByte()); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

What does the `WebBrowserIsoStorage;` in the path mean (line 2)?

Comment: This came from a certain MSDN forum, didn't it? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That uri string is a relative [Pack UrI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) (see Table 2 in the linked page for a similar example).

The first part (`WebBrowserIsoStorage`) is the assembly in which the resource (the textmate.jpg image) lives. The second part is the path to the resource within the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

`WebBrowserIsoStorage` is the [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx) location for the Web browser.

Answer (score 0):

It means that there is an assembly in the system, that is called `WebBrowserIsoStorage`, and by following the component with a path after it, you are trying to access its resources.